# Increment and Decrement: Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, e-commerce

I am doing an e-commerce project. I am currently trying to create the functionality of the quantity amount for each new added item. However, when the amount of one item altered, though it does not change the other item's quantity, when you try to alter the other item's quantity it starts from the number of the previous item's quantity.

For example, if I make the quantity of 'item1' = 3. Then if I adjust 'item2', whether I increase or decrease, it starts from 3, instead of 1.

I think I am maybe complicating it for myself I am still new to JavaScript.

```
const quantityIncDec = function (plus, minus) {
  let quantity = 1;

  plus.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
      quantity++;
      this.parentElement.children[1].textContent = quantity;
    });
  });

  minus.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
      if (quantity > 1) {
        quantity--;
        this.parentElement.children[1].textContent = quantity;
      }
    });
  });
};

// Add to Cart Preview
btnAddCart.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const markup = `
    <li class="index-preview-list-item">
    <img src="${this.parentElement.children[0].src}" alt="" />
      <div>
        <h4 class="product-name">${this.parentElement.children[1].textContent}</h4>
        <div class="quantity">
          <button class="btn btn-plus">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
          </button>
          <p class="quantity-value">1</p>
          <button class="btn btn-minus">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-minus"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-delete">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i>
      </button>
    </li>
    `;

    clearPreviewText(previewTextCart);
    cartPreviewContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);

    const btnPlus = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-plus');
    const btnMinus = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-minus');
    quantityIncDec(btnPlus, btnMinus);

    const btnDelete = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-delete');
    deleteItem(btnDelete);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `let` keyword is used to create a block-scoped variable. So, you will have a single instance of that variable in its block. Let's illustrate this in two examples:

```js
let quantity = 0;
for (let button of document.querySelectorAll(".btn")) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert(++quantity);
    });
}
```

```html
<input class="btn" type="button" value="1">
<input class="btn" type="button" value="2">
<input class="btn" type="button" value="3">
<input class="btn" type="button" value="4">
<input class="btn" type="button" value="5">
<input class="btn" type="button" value="6">
<input class="btn" type="button" value="7">
```

As you can see, the counter is being updated whenever you click on a button and it does not separately keep track of each button's `quantity`. This is your mistake. Now, let's see a corrected example, where `quantity` is created in the correct block:

```js
for (let button of document.querySelectorAll(".btn")) {
    let quantity = 0;
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert(++quantity);
    });
}
```

```html
<input class="btn" type="button" value="1">
<input class="btn" type="button" value="2">
<input class="btn" type="button" value="3">
<input class="btn" type="button" value="4">
<input class="btn" type="button" value="5">
<input class="btn" type="button" value="6">
<input class="btn" type="button" value="7">
```

If you click on different buttons here, then you will see that each is having "its own" `quantity`. So, having said this, let's apply a similar fix for your code:

```
const quantityIncDec = function (plus, minus) {
  //quantity is no longer defined here, because then it's out of the loop's
  //block and its value will be shared between the buttons

  plus.forEach(button => {
    //Instead, we create quantity here and it will be therefore in the
    //context of the "current" button
    let quantity = 1;
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
      quantity++;
      this.parentElement.children[1].textContent = quantity;
    });
  });

  minus.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
      if (quantity > 1) {
        quantity--;
        this.parentElement.children[1].textContent = quantity;
      }
    });
  });
};

// Add to Cart Preview
btnAddCart.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const markup = `
    <li class="index-preview-list-item">
    <img src="${this.parentElement.children[0].src}" alt="" />
      <div>
        <h4 class="product-name">${this.parentElement.children[1].textContent}</h4>
        <div class="quantity">
          <button class="btn btn-plus">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
          </button>
          <p class="quantity-value">1</p>
          <button class="btn btn-minus">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-minus"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-delete">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i>
      </button>
    </li>
    `;

    clearPreviewText(previewTextCart);
    cartPreviewContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);

    const btnPlus = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-plus');
    const btnMinus = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-minus');
    quantityIncDec(btnPlus, btnMinus);

    const btnDelete = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-delete');
    deleteItem(btnDelete);
  });
});
```

EDIT

The solution above was ignoring that a minus button also has to work with the same quantity, so I apply a fix for it:

```
const quantityIncDec = function (plus, minus) {
  //quantity is no longer defined here, because then it's out of the loop's
  //block and its value will be shared between the buttons
  let limit = Math.max(plus.length, minus.length);
  for (index = 0; index < limit; index++) {
    if (plus.length > index) {
      let plusButton = plus[index];
      plusButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        quantity++;
        this.parentElement.children[1].textContent = quantity;
      });
    }
    if (minus.length > index) {
      let minusButton = minus[index];
      minusButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (quantity > 1) {
          quantity--;
          this.parentElement.children[1].textContent = quantity;
        }
      });
    }
  }

};

// Add to Cart Preview
btnAddCart.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const markup = `
    <li class="index-preview-list-item">
    <img src="${this.parentElement.children[0].src}" alt="" />
      <div>
        <h4 class="product-name">${this.parentElement.children[1].textContent}</h4>
        <div class="quantity">
          <button class="btn btn-plus">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
          </button>
          <p class="quantity-value">1</p>
          <button class="btn btn-minus">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-minus"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-delete">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i>
      </button>
    </li>
    `;

    clearPreviewText(previewTextCart);
    cartPreviewContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);

    const btnPlus = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-plus');
    const btnMinus = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-minus');
    quantityIncDec(btnPlus, btnMinus);

    const btnDelete = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-delete');
    deleteItem(btnDelete);
  });
});
```

Comment: This was so helpful in understanding the let key word thank you! I tried this way, and it solved the problem but now the minus button does not work. I'm assuming because now it doesnt recognize the quantity variable with it being within plus button. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Neelam of course, let me edit my answer...

Comment: @Neelam applied an edit. So, since you need to group two buttons per quantity, I'm doing an indexed loop (always checking for limits to avoid errors) and adding the corresponding event to the plus and minus button at the given index, the two will share the same `quantity` variable. If my answer/edit solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Neelam "I'm assuming because now it doesnt recognize the quantity variable with it being within plus button." Yes, that's correct, it was declared in the block of the plus loop. Since you want the same quantity to be shared between corresponding buttons, I have wrapped a loop around both plus and minus, referencing the correct plus and minus button by index and defined `quantity` to be a variable in that loop's block, so both the plus and minus button are using the same `quantity`, sharing it as long as they are on the same index.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, If I understood your question correctly. The problem in your source code is, that the only single quantity variable you are using for all of your products. But each product has it's own quantity state, therefore In your case, If you will modify quantity of one product, you will also modify initial quantity state of all another products.

Inside listener callback method, you must firstly get the previous quantity state for the current product and after that increment that value. Also another way is for example save current product quantities into array variable, and then you will need firstly find the initial quantity state from right array value, then increment and then save back modified value to that array.

```
// ...or ungly but most simple solution, take text content, convert to Int, then increment and store back to the element
this.parentElement.children[1].textContent = parseInt(this.parentElement.children[1].textContent)+1;
```

Edited answer:

```
// Write Javascript code!
const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<div id="basket">Basket</div>`;

let items = [
  {
    id: 24,
    name: 'halabala',
    qty: 10,
  },
];

function Basket() {
  const render = () => {
    const elBasket = document.getElementById('basket');
    elBasket.innerHTML = ''; // Remove all childs from previous render
    // console.log(elBasket);

    if (items.length) {
      items.forEach((item) => {
        const that = this;
        const elDiv = document.createElement('div');

        const elSpan = document.createElement('span');
        elSpan.innerText = '   ' + item.name + ' (' + item.qty + ')';

        const btnPlus = document.createElement('button');
        btnPlus.innerText = '+';
        btnPlus.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          Basket().incrementItem(item.id);
        });

        const btnMinus = document.createElement('button');
        btnMinus.innerText = '-';
        btnMinus.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          Basket().decrementItem(item.id);
        });

        elDiv.appendChild(btnPlus);
        elDiv.appendChild(btnMinus);
        elDiv.appendChild(elSpan);
        elBasket.appendChild(elDiv);
      });
    }
  };

  return {
    init: () => {
      render();
    },

    addItem: (itemId, itemName, gty = 1) => {
      items.push({ id: itemId, name: itemName, qty: qty });
      render();
    },

    removeItem: (itemId) => {
      items = items.filter((i) => i.id != itemId);
      render();
    },

    incrementItem: (itemId) => {
      const item = items.find((i) => i.id === itemId);
      if (!item)
        throw new Error('Unable to increment, because item not found!');

      item.qty++;
      render();
    },

    decrementItem: (itemId) => {
      const item = items.find((i) => i.id === itemId);
      if (!item)
        throw new Error('Unable to decrement, because item not found!');

      item.qty--;
      render();
    },

    clearBasket: () => {
      items = [];
    },
  };
}

Basket().init();
```

Comment: This works! but I found that when I add a new item, the item before it will go up but the number of items added insted of by one. So if theres three items, then no.1 will go up by 3, no.2 will go up by 2, and no.3 will go up by one. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Neelam To eliminate all problems, the better solution is split data of items and manipulate only with data. And after each update od data, only refresh or set new values to the buttons (UI). I edited the answer, you have prepated methods for add item, remove item, increment item, dectement item, clear all items and you can add everything, what you want. At the end, after data manipulation, you need to refresj UI, averything according to that is in render() private method. This example is not optimize, it's only to understand, that split data separately is much better.

Comment: @Neelam Stackblitz example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vrl4eb?file=index.js